# Format java snippet in jsp file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, formatting

When I format automatically my jsp files in eclipse the java code in brackets <% {javacode} %> gets also formatted.

Which formatter options are considered in this case?

I am asking because the formatter wraps my lines after 72 characters and I want to change this behaviour.

Comment: You can increase the 72 characters limit to something like a 200.

Comment: And where can I find this option? I did already increase every option I know in eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to set the `Line Width` under `Web > HTML Files > Editor`.

[image]

Comment: I did that already and it does not work. But if I take out my javascript out of the site embedded in <script>-tags it works. Its really weired.

Answer (score 0):

Java and JavaScript aren't the same as each other, nor the same as HTML. Have you tried modifying the formatting settings for those languages, using their preference pages?

Comment: I know that these languages are not the same. I am working for more than 10 years in web development and I know this. My java source code did not get formatted right, not my javascript code, and they influenced each other. See my comment below where I described that already.